# Conjugate prior for univariate normal with same mean and unknown sum of two variances

Tags: bayesian, variance, conjugate-prior, inverse-gamma-distribution

I have a Bayesian inference problem where the likelihood function is conditioned on **two** unknown variances.

$$\log\mathcal{L}(d\mid \sigma_n,\sigma_s) = -\frac{1}{2} \log (\sigma_n^2 + \sigma_s^2) -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(d-\mu)}{\sigma_n^2 + \sigma_s^2}^2$$

where $\mu$ is a known quantity.
I would like to find a conjugate prior $\pi(\sigma_s, \sigma_n)$, possibly separable
$$\pi(\sigma_s, \sigma_n) = \pi_s(\sigma_s)\pi_n(\sigma_n)$$.

Is there a standard procedure to construct it?
If one of the two variances is known, then the correct prior is the [scaled inverse $\chi^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_inverse_chi-squared_distribution) or equivalently, to the [inverse gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution).

Comment: In the likelihood function those two variances only appears via their sum, so it looks like they should not be identifiable? I guess you need to tell us more context for anybody to help

Comment: I have written a MWE to avoid confusing readers with the details.
Here are some more details:
1. on one hand, I will need to perform this inference multiple times on many different datasets, hence stochastic sampling is prohibitive. This is the reason for conjugate priors.
2. on the other hand, the model contains two variances because they are directly related to the (two) processes generating the data. 

In a realistic setup, we have a certain degree of prior knowledge on both, and I would like to understand whether the parameters of conjugate priors (if they exists) can be tuned to it.